# Elementary proof of when -2 is a quadratic residue modulo an odd prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

Mathworld says that $-2$ is a quadratic residue modulo a prime $p$ if and only if $p=8n+1$ or $p=8n+3$, though I don't understand their explanation.

I have seen elementary proofs that $-1$ is a quadratic residue [if and only if](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122048/1-is-a-quadratic-residue-modulo-p-if-and-only-if-p-equiv-1-pmod4) $p=8n+1$, and $2$ is a quadratic residue [if and only if](https://mixedmath.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/an-elementary-proof-of-when-2-is-a-quadratic-residue/) $p = 8n+1$ or $p=8n-1$, but I cannot find (or come up with) a proof for 2. Is there some way to combine the results of $-1$ and $2$, or is there a completely separate way?

Much appreciation, thanks.

Comment: Incidentally: $-1$ is a quad. residue mod $p$ if $p = 4n+1$ (not just $8n+1$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the results can be combined, and you can do it yourself. Just use the general fact that (i) the product of two residues, or two non-residues, is a residue, and (ii) the product of a residue and a non-residue, is a non-residue.

**Comment:** One way to identify the primes for which $2$ is a quadratic residue is to use Euler's Criterion.  The Euler Criterion can also be used to deal directly with $-2$.