# Prove $7\mid x^2+y^2$ iff $7\mid x$ and $7\mid y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

The question is basically in the title: Prove $7\mid x^2+y^2$ iff $7\mid x$ and $7\mid y$

I get how to do it from $7\mid $ and $7\mid y$ to $7\mid x^2+y^2$, but not the other way around.

Help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered the remainders that $x^2$ leaves modulo 7?

Comment: This is a small problem, so you should consider the brute force method of checking all the alternatives before asking for help. Some obvious reductions help: If one of $x,y$ is divisible by seven so must the other. Also the symmetries $x\leftrightarrow -x$, $y\leftrightarrow-y$, $x\rightarrow y$ cut the number of remaining cases down from 36 to 6. Not hard.

Comment: See also: [How to show that $7\mid a^2+b^2$ implies $7\mid a$ and $7\mid b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/723739)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$x^2,y^2$  can be $0^2\equiv0, (\pm1)^2\equiv1,(\pm2)^2\equiv4, (\pm3)^2\equiv2\pmod 7$

Observe that for no combination except $0,0$ of $x^2+y^2 \equiv0\pmod 7$

---

Alternatively,

If $(7,xy)=1, x^2+y^2\equiv0\pmod 7\implies \left(\frac xy\right)^2\equiv-1\pmod 7$

But we  [know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122048/1-is-a-quadratic-residue-modulo-p-if-and-only-if-p-equiv-1-pmod4) $-1$ is a Quadratic residue $\pmod p$ iff prime $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$

Comment: Thank you. And thank you all - you guys opened my eyes to many ways of solving the one problem I never would've seen with the lecturer I have being very brief with the content.

Comment: Sir you proved that $x^2+y^2$ is divisible by 7 if $7|x$ and $7|y$. But since it is an [if and only if](http://www.d.umn.edu/~jgallian/Proofs.html) so you must also prove that when $7|x$ and $7|y$ then $7|x^2+y^2$. If I'm making any mistake then kindly correct me.

Comment: @Singh, If $7|x, x=7m$ where $m$ is any integer

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+y^2 \equiv \mod 7 \implies x^2 \equiv k \mod 7$ and $y^2 \equiv 7-k \mod 7$

And any $a^2 \equiv 0,1,4,2\mod 7$(Why?) $\implies k=0$

Answer (score 1):

This is a more general fact.

To quote [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_modulus):
If $p$ is prime and $p ≡ 3 \pmod 4$ the negative of a residue modulo $p$ is a nonresidue and the negative of a nonresidue is a residue.

Therefore for $p$ is prime with $p ≡ 3 \pmod 4,$ $p\mid x^2+y^2\iff p\mid x$  and $p\mid y$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\ mod\ 7\!:\  x,y\not\equiv 0,\ \ x^2 \equiv -y^2\ \stackrel{cube}{\Rightarrow}\, 1\equiv x^6\equiv -y^6\equiv -1\:\Rightarrow\Leftarrow,\ $ via little Fermat.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of modular arithmetic. If $a|b$, then $b\equiv 0 \pmod{a}$. So you know that

$$
x^2+y^2 \equiv 0 \mod 7
$$
You wish to show that there are no other values of $x$ and $y$ that will satisfy this. One approach is, as lab bhattacharjee notes, direct evaluation of the possibilities. Alternatively, you can suppose that $y\equiv nx\pmod{7}$ for some integer $n$. Then we have
$$
x^2(1+n^2)\equiv 0 \mod 7
$$
Therefore, if $x\not\equiv 0\pmod7$, then we must have that
$$
n^2\equiv -1 \mod 7
$$
However, there is no integer $n$ satisfying this condition. Therefore, $x\equiv 0\pmod7$. And since $y\equiv nx\equiv0\pmod7$, we have that $7|x$ and $7|y$.

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, $7$ divides $x^2+y^2=(x+iy)(x-iy)$. Therefore, there exists $a+ib \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $x+iy=7(a+ib)$ or $x-iy=7(a+ib)$. You deduce that $7$ divide $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.