# Prime numbers problem - discrete math

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

> Show that natural numbers of the form $n^2+1$ are not divisible by primes of the form $p=4k-1$.

I can't really find a place to start.

Thank you very much in advance,

Yaron.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122048/1-is-a-quadratic-residue-modulo-p-if-and-only-if-p-equiv-1-pmod4

Comment: hi, i can't find any similarity between the 2 questions

Comment: @user76508, if $p$ divides $n^2+1, -1\equiv n^2\pmod p$

Comment: $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv −1 \pmod p$ if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \implies p \not \equiv -1( \mod 4)$, do you see that?

Comment: @ lab bhattacharjee got it, thanks

Comment: @Inceptio I get that, but i don't understand how they showed that $p=1 (mod4)$.

Comment: I don't really understand what they were trying to do

Comment: @user76508 : 

(1) $\;\left(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\right)^*\;$ is a (cyclic) group ;

(2) $\;|\left(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\right)^*|=p-1\;$ ;

(3) if $\,x\in\left(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\right)^*\;$ and $\,x^2=-1\;$ , then $\;ord(x)=4\implies 4\mid (p-1)\implies p=1\pmod 4\,$

Comment: @DonAntonio why is $ord(x)=4$?

Comment: @user76508 , because $\;x^4=(x^2)^2=(-1)^2=1\;$ and clearly $\,x^m\neq 1\;$ for natural $\,m<3\,$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio ok got that.

and after i now that $ord(x)=4$, why do i know that $4|p-1$?

Comment: @user76508, this is a basic fact of group theory. Haven't you covered that already? If you have you may want to refresh your memory with Lagrange's Theorem (google it), but if you haven't then this won't help you...

Comment: @DonAntonio got it, thank you very much. I probably should refresh my memory

Comment: @user76508: Now that you have got your solution. Write an answer for it and accept it. So that it doesn't keep popping in *unanswered* list of questions.

Comment: This should be marked as a duplicate.