# Prove that every odd prime divisor of $n^2+100$ is of the form $12k+1$ or $12k+5$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

Prove that every odd prime divisor of $n^2+100$ is of the form $12k+1$ or $12k+5$.

I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: We could also say "... is of the form $4k+1$". Does that help finding the relevant condition?

Answer (score 4):

If $p|(n^2+100),  n^2\equiv-100\pmod p\iff (n\cdot (10)^{-1})^2\equiv-1\pmod p$

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122048/1-is-a-quadratic-residue-modulo-p-if-and-only-if-p-equiv-1-pmod4), $p\equiv1\pmod 4$

$\implies p\equiv1,5,9\pmod{12}$ but $p$ needs to be prime

Observe that $p\equiv9\pmod {12}\equiv0\pmod3$