# Does $x^2+1$ have roots in $Z_{103}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

I am trying to figure out if $x^2+1$ has any roots in $Z_{103}[x]$, but I don't have any idea of how I should find the answer. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122048/1-is-a-quadratic-residue-modulo-p-if-and-only-if-p-equiv-1-pmod4

Answer (score 1):

No.  Such a root cannot exist modulo $p$ when $p$ is one less than a multiple of $4$.