# Given natural numbers a and b such that a^2+b^2 is divisible by 21, prove that the same sum of squares is also divisible by 441.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Tried factoring, but I am not getting any ideas.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122048/1-is-a-quadratic-residue-modulo-p-if-and-only-if-p-equiv-1-pmod4

Comment: works for any product of  primes $4k+3$

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out $a^2+b^2$ $\mod 3$ and $\mod 7$.

For any integer $a$ : $a^2\mod3$ is either $0$ or $1$.

for any integer $a$ : $a^2\mod7$ could be $0$, $1$, $2$ or $4$.

So, if $a^2+b^2$ is divisible by $21$, both $a$ and $b$ are.

Comment: Then, how is it divisible by 441?

Comment: chinese remainder theorem @RaahilRai

Comment: Oh! Yess. Thanks

Comment: More simply, if $a = 21m, b=21n$, then $a^2 + b^2 = 21^2m^2 + 21^2n^2 = 441(m^2 + n^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$a^2+b^2$$ is only divisible by $21$ if $a^2$ and $b^2$ is divisible by $21$ this means that $a$ and $b$ is divisible by $21$  but then must $a^2$ and $b^2$ is divisible by $21^2=441$