# Finding the modulo class of $n \mod 7$ from that of $n^2 + n^3 \equiv 0\pmod 7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The remainders of $n\mod 7$ will have the set of equivalence classes with residue: 
$\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

The remainders of $n^2\mod 7$ will have the set of equivalence classes with residue: $\{0,1,4,2\}$.

The remainders of $n^3\mod 7$ will have the set of equivalence classes with residue: $\{0,1,6\}$.

Regarding the $n^2 + n^3  \equiv 0\pmod 7$, I have taken the following approach:

Simply pairwise add the two sets given for $n^2$ and $n^3$. The pairwise combinations that add up to $7$ and hence lead to $ \equiv 0\pmod 7$ are :

(i) $1,6$

So, $n^2$ should have residue $1$; while $n^3$ should have residue $6$.

For, $n^2$ the values of n that satisfy are: $1, 6$

For, $n^3$ the values of n that satisfy are: $3, 5, 6$

So, the value of $n = 6k$ $ \forall k \in \mathbb {Z}$.

---

I am unable to have a theoretical basis for such pair-wise addition, and request the same; even if I am correct.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122048/1-is-a-quadratic-residue-modulo-p-if-and-only-if-p-equiv-1-pmod4

Comment: Solve it the same way you would solve the equation $n^2+n^3=0$.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thanks for a great pointer for theoretical basis. But, still my problem seems childish comparatively. I request to draw a link between the two. I hope you would definitely accede to this request, as you have given such a great link too. Even a small hint by you may help me a lot to draw an improbable link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $7$ is prime and $n^2+n^3\equiv0\pmod{7}$ you have that either $n^2\equiv0\pmod{7}$ or $n+1\equiv0\pmod{7}$. Thus
$$
n\equiv0\pmod{7}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
n\equiv6\pmod{7}
$$