# Properties of numbers which are $x^2 + 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Why is $x^2 + 1$ not divisible by $11$ where $x$ is an integer.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122048/1-is-a-quadratic-residue-modulo-p-if-and-only-if-p-equiv-1-pmod4

Answer (score 1):

You can verify by hand that -1=10 is not a square modulo 11:
$$
1^2=1 \\ 
2^2=4 \\
3^2=9 =-2 \\
4^2=16=5 \\
5^2=25=3 \\
6^2=36=3 \\
7^2=49=5 \\
8^2=64=9 \\
9^2=81=4 \\
10^2=100=1 \\
11^2=0^2=0 \\
$$
.
If there was such an x as described in your question, then its square would be -1 modulo 11.

Answer (score 0):

It is special case of this theorem:

If $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and $p\mid a^2+b^2$ then $p\mid a$ and $p\mid b$.

In your case: if $11\mid x^2+1$ then $11\mid 1$, a contradiction.