# Do there exist numbers of the form $n^2+1$ with arbitrarily many prime factors?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

This is actually two questions:
1.Do there exist numbers of the form $n^2+1$ with arbitrarily many *unique* prime factors?
2.Do there exist numbers of the form $n^2+1$ with arbitrarily many prime factors?
I think an approach using gaussian primes might help,
$$n^2+1=(n+i)(n-i)$$
let $n=c^2$
$$(c^2 + i)(c^2-i)...$$
but from here I haven't managed to make anything productive out of this approach.
Note: the primes in the question are normal natural number primes.

Comment: What do you mean by unique?

Comment: different prime factors, i.e. $12$ has two unique prime factors $2,3$, and three prime factors $12=2\cdot 2\cdot 3$

Comment: Oh ok, usually when we talk about orime factors, if $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdotp_2^{a_2}....\cdotp_m^{a_m}$, $n$ has $m$ prime factors.

Comment: Yeah, I probably should have mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will elaborate what Ravi said for you.

$n_i^2\equiv -1\pmod{p_i}$ has a solution if $-1$ is a quadratic residue. A known formula is $$\bigg(\frac{-1}{p}\bigg)=(-1)^\frac{p-1}{2}$$ thus, if and only if $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ $-1$ is a quadratic residue.

(search up quadratic residues and laws for more information).

Now simply consider $n$ according to the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score 4):

Yes and yes.  In fact, given any finite set of primes $p_i \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, there exists an integer $n$ such that $n^2 + 1$ is divisible by all of the $p_i$.  Proof:  each of the congruences $n_i^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{p_i}$ individually has two solutions modulo $p_i$; choose one of the two for each $i$, and use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find an $n$ congruent to each $n_i$ modulo $p_i$.

Comment: can you elaborate? why does $n_i^2\equiv-1 \pmod {p_i}$ have solutions? is it because $p_i\equiv1 \pmod 4$

Comment: @razivo .If $G$ is a finite commutative group with identity $1$ then $\prod_{x\in G}x=\prod_{x\in S}x$ where $S=\{x\in G: x^2=1\}$ because the other members of $G$ cancel out in pairs. In particular, if $p$ is a prime and $G=\{1,...,p-1\}$ with multiplication mod $p$ then $S=\{1,p-1\}$ so $(p-1)!\equiv -1 \mod p.$ (Wilson's Theorem.)  So if also $4|(p-1)$ then  with $p=4c+1$ we have $-1\equiv  (p-1)! \equiv (2c)!\prod_{j=1}^{2c}(p-j)\equiv (2c)!^2 \mod p.$

Comment: More discussion of this theorem, including Daniel's proof and some others:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122048/1-is-a-quadratic-residue-modulo-p-if-and-only-if-p-equiv-1-pmod4 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2731641/if-p-is-prime-and-p-equiv-1-mod-4-then-the-congruence-x2-equiv.