# Primes dividing an integer polynomial $x^8 + 8x^6y^2 -2x^4y^4 + 8x^2y^6 + y^8$ are congruent to 1 mod $4$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

I need to prove that if $p\neq 2$ divides the integer polynomial
$$x^8 + 8x^6y^2 -2x^4y^4 + 8x^2y^6 + y^8\in\mathbb{Z}[x,y],$$ $gcd(x,y)=1,$ then $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}.$ Any ideas?

Edit (the OPs reaction to the hint that this is a sum of two squares):

> If $p|a^2+b^2=(a+bi)(a−bi)$, then wlog $p|a+bi$ which means that $a+bi≡0\pmod p$, so $i=\sqrt{−1}$ is defined modulo $p$. That means that $-1$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$, so $p\equiv1 \mod p$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, $p\neq 2,$ I will edit that, thank you!

Comment: That polynomial is equal to
$$(x^2+y^2)^4+4x^2y^2(x^2-y^2)^2.$$ A sum of two squares. Show that this implies that $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. You need to cater for the possibility that both those squares are themselves multiples of $p$. I think some kind of a descent follows.

Comment: @Aqua I appreciate the vote of confidence. There is the problem with the descent part. Also, I will search f0r duplicates before checking it out further.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen if $p|a^2+b^2=(a+bi)(a-bi),$ then wlog $p|a+bi$ which means that $a+bi\equiv 0 \pmod{p},$ so $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is defined modulo $p.$ That means that -1 is a quadratic residue mod $p,$ so $p\equiv 1 \pmod{p}.$ Does that sound right to you?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, how did you find that expression as a sum of two squares?

Comment: A fair question @lhf :-) Something about it suggested that it might be. Only even powers, general appearance? May be that was an intuition thing from having seen my share of questions like this? I thought it would be a field norm of some kind, when similar conclusions about the prime factors can often be drawn?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, all good reasons. Thanks. Yet not trivial.

Comment: Correct, Nom. That is more or less the reasoning.

Comment: Nom, if you don't mind, please add the contents of that comment of yours into the question body. That will show the passers-by that you worked on the hint. And therefore it will pre-empt further votes to close the question for lacking context.

Comment: As you are a new user our expectations may be somewhat unclear to you. I recommend that you study [the guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: Like that :-) ${}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof can be based on the following

**Fact.** If an odd prime $p$ is a factor of the sum $x^2+y^2$ such that $x$ and $y$ are not multiples of $p$, then $p\equiv1\pmod4$.

**Proof.** Without loss of generality $p\nmid y$. Therefore we can divide the congruence
$$
x^2\equiv -y^2\pmod p
$$
by $y^2$, and conclude that there exists an integer $z\equiv xy^{-1}$ such that $z^2\equiv-1\pmod p$. This is [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/122048/11619)
 to be possible only when $p\equiv1\pmod4$.

---

The octic polynomial in the question can be written as a sum of two squares:
$$
x^8 + 8x^6y^2 -2x^4y^4 + 8x^2y^6 + y^8=(x^2+y^2)^4+4x^2y^2(x^2-y^2)^2.
$$
If neither $a=(x^2+y^2)^2$ nor $b=2xy(x^2-y^2)$ is divisible by $p$, then the other cannot be either. Hence the Fact bites, and allows us to conclude that $p\equiv1\pmod4$.

But if $p\mid a$, then $p\mid x^2+y^2$, and we can repeat the argument. Observe that the assumption $\gcd(x,y)=1$ rules out the possibility that both $x$ and $y$ would be divisible by $p$.