# Let $p$ be an odd prime, and let $a$ and $b$ be integers such that $(p, ab) = 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $p$ divides $a^2+b^2$ , then $ p \equiv \ 1 \pmod 4$.

I know that both $a$ and $b$ are coprimes with $p$ but i dont know what to do next.

Comment: Here $(ab^{-1})^2\equiv-1\pmod4$. This implies $p\equiv1\pmod4$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/122048/11619).

Answer (score 0):

$b$ is invertible $\bmod p$, i.e., there is $c$ with $bc\equiv 1\pmod p$. Then $(ac)^2+1=c^2(a^2+b^2)\equiv 0\pmod 4$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: How did we get to the mod 4 there? And i am afraid i still can't see what to do.