# How do you solve $x*x = 1009732533765288 \mod 1009732533765289$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, linear-diophantine-equations

How do you solve $x*x = 1009732533765288 \mod 1009732533765289$? Wolframalpha when you plug that in has the answers as:

$x \equiv 389427288088687 \mod 1009732533765289$

and

$x \equiv 620305245676602 \mod 1009732533765289$

both of $389427288088687 + 620305245676602 = 1009732533765289$.  I'm wondering how it solves these so I can write a program to solve these types of equations. Thanks.

Comment: This is easier to solve when you observe that this is equivalent to $$x^2\equiv-1\bmod{1009732533765289}$$

Comment: Observe that $1009732533765289$ is a prime number and if $x^2 \equiv a \pmod n$, then $(-x)^2 \equiv a \pmod n$.
You now can use a Wilson's Theorem argument to find one value for $x$.

Comment: $A + B =M$ should not be surprising as $A+B = M \implies B \equiv - A \pmod M$ and $A^2 \equiv (-A)^2$.  So if we have $x^2 =k$ you will *always* have a pair of solutions that add to $M$.  So we want $A^2 +1 \equiv 0 \pmod  M$.

Comment: "Observe that 1009732533765289 is a prime number"  I'm not sure how to "observe" that.  :)

Comment: it's odd and  has a  2 mod 3 difference in quantity of 1 mod 3 digits and 2 mod 3 digits,  therefore it's $6k\pm 1$ at least

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did this problem come from? Or, maybe more directly, 'why $1009732533765289$?'.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki  I noticed that many primes have a solution where the answers added together equal the prime, so I chose 1009732533765289. It could have easily been 1009, whose answers are 469 and 540.  I'm just looking for a solution on how to get the answers in the case the prime number i have is in the form as the other answers are saying it has. I don't think non primes have this feature, but i haven't tested too many numbers

Comment: Related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122048/1-is-a-quadratic-residue-modulo-p-if-and-only-if-p-equiv-1-pmod4)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Also i noticed those answers always pass the 2nd pow(x, 2, z) part of the MillerRabin test, so i was interested in them in general.

Comment: @fleablood, of course, using some software. Why would someone make this math by hand? lol

Comment: Use the Tonelli–Shanks algorithm (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to use the fact that the number is odd to avoid technicalities. Since your number has size approximately $10^{15}$ it can be factored in a variety of ways.

One could then solve it for each $p^k$. To do this one can find a primitive root $r$ in the normal way and just letting $x=r^{(p-1)p^k/4}$ or $x=r^{3(p-1)p^k/4}$ (there is no solution if $p$ is not congruent to $1\bmod 4$).

Then one can use the Chinese remainder theorem to find a solution that works for all primes simultaneously.

If the number is even we do the following: If the number is a multiple of $4$ there is no solution, and if the number is not a multiple of $4$ then just make sure that the number you get at the end with CRT is odd and we are good to go.