# $2^{4n+1} \equiv 1 \pmod{8n+7}$, this has been bugging me

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

Here is the question:

> Suppose that $p$ is an odd prime. The law of quadratic reciprocity says that $x^2\equiv 2\pmod p$ has a solution. if $p\equiv1 \text{ or } 7 \pmod 8$. Prove that $2^{4n+3}\equiv1 \pmod{8n+1}$. $8n+1$ is a prime

I honestly don't know where to start, I tried starting it with Fermat's Theorem because it looked similar to that, $a^{p-1} = 1 \pmod p$, but it didn't lead me anywhere, or I missed something.

Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: http://mixedmath.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/an-elementary-proof-of-when-2-is-a-quadratic-residue/  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84951/elementary-proof-of-when-2-is-a-quadratic-residue-modulo-an-odd-prime

Answer (score 2):

If $2$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod p$, then $\exists a\in\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ s.t. $a^2\equiv 2\pmod p$.

In the case $p=8n+7$ where $p$ is prime, $$2^{4n+3}\equiv a^{8n+6}\equiv a^{\phi(p)}\equiv 1\pmod p$$

Answer (score 0):

$\rm mod\ p\!:\ 0\not\equiv a \equiv x^2 \Rightarrow\ a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv x^{p-1}\equiv 1\ $ by  little Fermat (and conversely: [Euler's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion))